# Why are generic types evaluated differently from concrete?

Tags: typescript, types

I got this type from the TS handbook:

```
type ToArray<Type> = Type extends any ? Type[] : never;
```

If you evaluate `ToArray<string & number>`, you get `never`;

However, if you evaluate `type Thing = (string & number) extends any ? never[] : never;`, `Thing` ends up as type `never[]`.

*Why?*

I've also tried writing out some more examples and none if it seems to help me understand:

```
type Thing = string & number; // type never
type OtherThing = Thing extends any ? Thing[] : never; // type never[]
type OtherOtherThing = ToArray<Thing>; // type never
```

Comment: ① You don't need to write `string & number` to see this, you can just use `never` directly.  ② The issue is that `ToArray` is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), and `never` is considered "the empty union".  See the other questions/answers for more info.